# Python 3.5 - Extract words from a file based on length

Tags: python, python-3.5

I was trying to make a fallout type hacking game based on the challenge from reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer. I am a Python beginner and im not quite sure how to perform one of the tasks i had in mind for a function.

i would like to define a function that reads words from a txt file and inputs a specific number of these words in a either a list in Python, or just prints them out to screen.

i know how to open the file and how to iterate through each line, but not how to "pick out" specific words based on length and print them out or enter them into a list.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is what i have so far:

```
def sortEasy():
    wordlist = open('ordlista.txt', 'r')
    for line in wordlist.readlines():
```

::EDIT::
with help this is what i have, and it achieves what i would like however i would like to limit the ammount to print outs (preferably a random selection of X ammount)

```
def sortEasy():
    wordlist = open('ordlista.txt', 'r')
    word = wordlist.readlines()
    for line in word:
        if len(line) == 6:
            print(line)
```

Comment: Can you show a coding attempt with example input and output data?

Comment: Updated with what i have, however im not sure that will be of any help, since i have not solved the output problem.

Comment: If you have a word to find, just go `if word in line: print(line)`

Comment: allright, thanks! this gets the desired result: